# Changing the default dreamweaver templates

Tags: php, html, templates, default, dreamweaver

I'm not sure if this is programming-related enough for stack overflow, but anyways...

I want to change the code that is created in dreamweaver when you create a new HTML file or PHP file.

For example, I want to replace the default doctype and HTML tag:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
```

with this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
```

How can I do this?

Comment: What version of Dreamweaver are you using?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

On Mac OS X, you'll find **Dreamweaver's** Document Type Declaration configurations at:

```
/Applications/Adobe Dreamweaver/Configuration/DocumentTypes
```

To add a new template for HTML5 documents, open the file `MMDocumentTypeDeclarations.xml`  and add a new element:

```
<documenttypedeclaration id="mm_html_5">
    <title>
        <MMString:loadString id="mmdocumenttypedeclarations/mm_html_5" />
    </title>

    <doctypedecl>
        <![CDATA[<!DOCTYPE HTML>]]>
    </doctypedecl>

    <rootelement>
        <![CDATA[<html></html>]]>
    </rootelement>

    <dtdcontext>html</dtdcontext>
    <dtdcontext>html5</dtdcontext>
    <dtdcontext>frameset_frame</dtdcontext>
    <dtdcontext>xslt</dtdcontext>
</documenttypedeclaration>
```

When creating new documents, Dreamweaver references `MMDocumentTypeDeclarations.xml` and matches the `<dtdcontext>` against the Page Type you selected in the New Document dialog box.

By modifying this XML file, you don't have to edit any of the templates in:

```
/Applications/Adobe Dreamweaver/Configuration/DocumentTypes/NewDocuments
```

---

If you're running **Dreamweaver CS5+** (version 11), Adobe already includes updated DTDs for HTML5:

[image: Dreamweaver New Document Dialog Box]

Which creates the following blank document:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
</body>

</html>
```

You can change which DOCTYPE is used by default when creating new documents by going into Dreamweaver's preferences:

[image: Dreamweaver New Document Preferences]

Answer (score 7):

In Windows, the file is at

```
C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Dreamweaver CS3\configuration\DocumentTypes\NewDocuments\Default.html
```

Replace "CS3" with your Adobe CS version.

Comment: thanks - found the mac version (cs5) had pretty much the same path `/Applications/Adobe Dreamweaver CS5/configuration/etc...`

Comment: OK, I want to say: THANK YOU SO MUCH!

Answer (score 0):

Still works in 2019 (using the subscription) in Win10:

```
C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Dreamweaver CC 2019\configuration\DocumentTypes\NewDocuments
```